# If $A + B$ is invertible, do we know if $A$ and $B$ are invertible separately?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification

If $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices and we know that $A + B$ is invertible, can we assume that $A$ and $B$ are invertible by themselves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Consider the counterexample $A = 0_{n\times n}$ and $B = I_{n}$.

Comment: Makes sense, was hopeful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just another (counter)example: let $1 \leq k < n$ and define $A : = \operatorname{diag}(1, \dots , \underbrace{1}_{k \text{th entry}} , 0, \dots, 0)$ and $B : = \operatorname{diag}(0, \dots, 0 , \underbrace{1}_{(k +1)\text{st entry}}, \dots, 1)$.

Comment: Thank you for your response!